# Inequality with random variables

Tags: probability, inequality

Let X be a random variable with pdf $$f(x)=\frac{x^me^{-x}}{m!},x\ge0,m\in N$$

Show that $P(0<X<2(m+1))\ge \frac{m}{m+1}$

Can somebody give me some ideas, please?

Comment: Have you tried Markov?

Comment: What is the theory allowed for you to solve it?

Comment: The way you have stated this question is confusing. Do you mean to say, for each $m\in\mathbb N$, let $X_m$ be a random variable with density $$f_m(x) = \frac{x^m e^{-x}}{m!}\cdot\mathsf 1_{(0,\infty)}\ \ \mathrm ? $$

Comment: How can I apply Markov here? Please answer fast